# MATLAB fft y axis meaning

Tags: matlab, fft

I have a time varying signal (a), which I take the fft of. I need to multiply a frequency dependent weighting factor by the fft's y axis value; however if I do:

```
xdft = fft(a);
xdft = xdft(1:length(x)/2+1); % only retaining the positive frequencies
freq = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;
```

And plot(freq,xdft) I get a peak fft value (y axis)of ~2000 at the correct frequency of the signal. But original signal peak value (amplitude) was ~46. I need to know how the numbers relate so I can weight the fft values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to divide by the DFT length. Take a look at [this example](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/fft-for-spectral-analysis.html).

Consider that the output of `fft` is complex. So if you want to plot the real power spectral density you should multiply the output by its complex conjugate like this:

```
Pyy = xdft.*conj(xdft)/L;
```

**Edit**:
For the amplitude spectrum you should do something like this:

```
xdft=abs(xdft/L); % same as sqrt(xdft.*conj(xdft))/L
Y=xdft(1:L/2+1); % copy half of data since the other half is redundant
Y(2:end-1) = 2*Y(2:end-1); % correct the amplitudes
```

**Edit 2**:
Just wanted to point to a really great book (the best in my opinion) which explains how fourier series work (and much more) in a really easy and understandable way.

*Alan V. Oppenheim, Alan S. Willsky, and S. Hamid Nawab.* 1996. **Signals & Systems (2nd Ed.).** Prentice-Hall, Inc., Upper Saddle River, NJ, USA.

Comment: At what point should I divide by the DFT length? If I do ts=0.1; t=0:ts:10; x=10*sin(t); L=length(t); fs=1/ts; xdft = fft(x); xdft = xdft(1:length(x)/2+1); xdft=xdft/length(xdft); freq = fs*(0:(L/2))/L; plot(freq,abs(xdft)); The y-axis of max. value is not the max. value of x.

Comment: @2one see the update on amplitude spectrum. Also consider the nyquist frequency and leakage effect.

Comment: Why Y[1] is not multiplied by 2?

Comment: @SantiagoGil because the first coefficient is frequency=0 so there is no complex conjugate part as for all other coefficients (there is always one part on the positive side and the same on the negative part of your "frequency" axis) You can see it like the is no negative frequency but the "energy" of each cofficient (>0) is spitted in half

Comment: Should ceil(L/2) be used instead of L/2 for odd sample sizes?